# removeAllAnimations() does not work for me in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi I checked all related question but I cannot solve my problem , I have an animate function like this;

```
    func startScrollSlideShow(sliderValue: Float) {
        
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)){
            //reach bottom
            
            UIScrollView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(sliderValue), delay: 0.5, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                self.scrollView.contentOffset.y += 3.5
            }) { (completion) in
                
                self.startScrollSlideShow(sliderValue: Float(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "sliderValue")!)!)
            }
        }else{
            
            return
        }
    }
```

and I have a button for stop this animate

```
    @objc func stopButton(sender: UIButton){
     
        self.scrollView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.scrollView.layer.layoutIfNeeded()
    
        
    
}
```

my stop button does not stop my animate function ☹️

Comment: Yes, I would not expect `self.scrollView.layer.removeAllAnimations()` to do anything. The scroll view’s layer was probably never animating to begin with. It’s easy for you to check whether that’s true.

Comment: so what should I do

Comment: You should use UIViewPropertyAnimator in order to have interactive animations.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator

Comment: okey thanks your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need `UIViewPropertyAnimator` class.
See this Documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator

> A property animator gives you programmatic control over the timing and execution of the animations. Specifically, you can start, pause, resume, and stop animations.
>
> -Apple Documentation-

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
```

Comment: teşekkürler cevabınız için hallettim :)